# Conditionals in SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a simple SQL Table like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce3fd/2/0

```
CREATE TABLE Trends
(Country varchar(250),
CTR int);

INSERT INTO Trends (Country, CTR)
VALUES ('America', 5),
('America', 10),
('America', 12),
('America', 40),
('England', 10),
('England', 410),
('England', 310),
('England', 210);
```

I want to set up a conditional that

A) Tests each individual country
B) Returns that country only if the CTR for ALL VALUES of that country are above 10

For example, in this table, "America" would not be returned because it has a CTR below 10. England would be returned because all if its CTRs are above 10.

Would I use the CASE item here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you can use a two part WHERE clause, one part will test for those with `ctr >= 10` and those countries that don't exist where `ctr < 10` and the following should work:

```
SELECT country, ctr
FROM Trends
WHERE ctr >= 10
  and country not in (select country
                      from trends
                      where ctr < 10);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce3fd/10)

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the subquery with:

```
SELECT Country
FROM Trends
GROUP BY Country
HAVING MIN(CTR) >= 10
```